# react socket io too many connection error

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to use socket io library before making chat application,
but i got some error which i can't solve it.
I'm using Nest Js for the backend and using React for frontend
Here is my code...
This is my backend code

```
import { Logger, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';

import {
ConnectedSocket,
MessageBody,
OnGatewayConnection,
OnGatewayDisconnect,
OnGatewayInit,
SubscribeMessage,
WebSocketGateway,
WebSocketServer,
WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';

import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/auth/auth.guard';
import { CREATE_CHANNEL, LEAVE_CHANNEL } from './chat.constants';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import { CreateChannelInput } from './dtos/create-channel.dto';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class ChatGateway
implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
constructor(private readonly chatService: ChatService) {}

private readonly logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');

@WebSocketServer()
server: Server;

afterInit() {
  this.logger.log(`Socket Server Init Complete`);
}

handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
  this.logger.log(`Client Connected: ${client.id}`);
}

handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
  this.logger.log(`Client Disconnected: ${client.id}`);
}

@SubscribeMessage('chat')
handleChat(
  @MessageBody() data: string,
  @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
): WsResponse<unknown> {
  console.log(data);
  return { event: 'chat', data };
}
```

}

This is my React code

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";

export const App = () => {
const socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
})
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form id="joinForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="title" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="topic" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="description" />
      <button>Join</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
};
```

This code is working normally, but when I see terminal, there is too many connections, as you can see.
This connection is repeating infinitely

```
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:20   [ChatGateway] Client Connected: MI3K8JHsIQRTVIgxAADi
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:20   [ChatGateway] Client Connected: 0_rSDPYVn0edAFdQAADj
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:20   [ChatGateway] Client Disconnected: WUlo7BQyyOWr8Tb5AADY
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:20   [ChatGateway] Client Disconnected: MJcYcQzYFkXIDxenAADZ
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:26   [ChatGateway] Client Connected: lUaOxmC9flTIb2lKAADk
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:26   [ChatGateway] Client Connected: c0deMKE3f58Dh8V_AADl
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:26   [ChatGateway] Client Disconnected: 2hDCbNYXMuFD8UzoAADa
[Nest] 76898   - 2021. 04. 26. 오후 4:12:26   [ChatGateway] Client Disconnected: QeScBxisKGENK6K2AADb
```

Comment: hello see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65600085/14522591)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping this code with a useEffect?

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id);
})
```